# Magento 2 Apache random 400 errors

Tags: php, apache, debian, magento2, http-status-code-400

Firstly I know how to deploy and work with files, I don't need answers saying 'redeploy static content' or 'clean cache' - experience from the research.

We having an issue on our development server. We have tested it with multiple projects, versions vary from **2.1.5** to the **2.2.3** open source.

After steps below we are receiving random 400 errors on some files (1-10 files). All those files are .js.
**FUN PART:**
After trying to get that file again (open in new tab) - everything is working fine, file is there, nothing bad.
After trying hard refresh again - again errors, but on other files.

After multiple soft refreshes (F5) - it looks good again.

Deployment mode - **Developer**

**Steps to reproduce**

- Install Magento without Sample date (tested with 2.2.3) - nothing configured.
- Set deployment mode Developer
- Deploy static content or just clean **/pub/static/**
- Chrome/Firefox - Inspector->Network tab->Disable cache (CHECKED)
- Clear site data on the browser.
- Create a product - for testing.
- Go to the website and then to the product (**no errors** even after hard refresh).
- Add product to the cart. (**no errors** even after hard refresh).
- Go for example to the category. (**errors** even after hard refresh).
- After clearing site data - everything looks fine again.
- We have reproduced this on multiple pc's / webbrowsers.

Server info:
PHP: 7.1.16
APACHE: 2.4.33
DirectAdmin 1.52.0
Debian: 8

Any suggestion what to do or what to check/change will be useful (except a stupid ones, no one likes those)

P.S. I was not sure if I should post it here or magento.stackexchange.com
Or if I can post on both websites at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Good morning all

After all we have found an issue. It was an apache module : mod_ruid2
After it was disabled - no more random 400 errors has appeared.

I hope this anwer will help someone even if this is an uncommon issue.

Answer (score 0):

To turn the module off, you need to do the following steps in the command line:

```
cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
./build set mod_ruid2 no
./build apache
```